# Jquery - Jeditable: How Reset to non-editable without page refresh

Tags: jquery, jeditable

is it possible to reset to original state after changing class and applying the jeditable plugin

say i have this example

```
<div class="non_edit" id="test1">test1</div>
<div class="non_edit" id="test2">test2</div>
```

and have this divs change class by this function

```
$('div.non_edit').addClass('edit').removeClass('non_edit');
```

and apply jeditable

```
$('.edit').editable('somepage.php');
```

now when i want to return to its 'non-editable' state i have this

```
$('div.edit').addClass('non_edit').removeClass('edit');
```

but still the 'changed' divs are editable, what im trying to do here is to set certain divs editable and non editable
, and also if there are any suggestions on how to do this in another way is much  appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('div.edit').addClass('non_edit').removeClass('edit').unbind('click.editable');
```

This will do it (tested on jeditable site using console). All this is doing is unbinding the event so nothing fires. You must use the correct namespacing as well - my code above works on the default.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks Inrbob, a follow up question, should i just use the unbind, since i only disabling the edit function? feedback to you when done

Comment: Changing the class name won't have an effect on whether the area is editable or not. Of course you may want a different style to apply when the area is editable or not, but it is optional.

Comment: awesome. thanks for this. exactly what i needed for an edit / unedit button